# Designing a slider menu in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, jetpack

Is there an inbuilt funtionality in jetpack compose to design a slider menu like this one that comes up from bottom (I am talking about the menu titled ADD MONEY TO EA DUMPLING)?

[image]

Would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bottom sheets.
A basic example of how to implement it.

```
var showBottomSheet by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()

if (showBottomSheet) {
    ModalBottomSheet(
        onDismissRequest = { showBottomSheet = false },
        sheetState = sheetState,
    ) {
        // Your bottom sheet content
    }
}
```